# How to get Popen stdout in realtime NOT line by line in Python?

Tags: python

In general this questions has a lot of answers but they are all limited to line by line reading. For example this code:

```
def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line

    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)
```

But there are output lines for example like this (where dots are added once in ~10s):

```
............................
```

They show progress of a task that runs. I don't want to stop output until the line is finished and only then print the whole dots line.

So I need to `yield string` when:

- I can **read a block of 1024 symbols** of output (or just the whole output)
- **there are ANY symbols** of output **and more then 1s passed** (no matter line is finished or not)

But I don't know how to do this.

p.s. Maybe a dup. Didn't find.

Comment: Fuzzy things. Redirect to `StringIO` but need check every cpu_clock for checking if time/size is reached. This related user/application output methods. Waste resource if haven't any output ! You want seperate every command/application-output on every buff or time but  **every communication need timer `server` or `client` base, can't use both because losing `RTC`  things(synchronisation)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux you can use [`stdbuf -o0`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) in front of the command you're executing to make its stdout become unbuffered (i.e. instantaneous).